# Foreigners knowledge about fasting in previous yugas

Tags: yuga, fasting

The following statement by Yudhistrira clarifies that foreigners are aware of (benefits of) fasting during Dwapara Yuga

> "Yudhishthira said, 'The disposition is seen, **O grandsire, in all the
> orders of men, including the very Mlechchhas, of observing fasts**. The
> reason, however, of this is not known to us. It has been heard by us
> that only Brahmanas and Kshatriyas should observe the vow of fasts.
> How, O grandsire, are the other orders to be taken as earning any
> merit by the observance of fasts? How have vows and fasts come to be
> observed by persons of all orders, O king? What is that end to which
> one devoted to the observance of fasts attains? It has been said that
> fasts are highly meritorious and that fasts are a great refuge. O
> prince of men, what is the fruit that is earned in this world by the
> man that observe fasts? By what means is one cleansed of one's sins?
> By what means doth one acquire righteousness? By what means, O best of
> the Bharatas, doth one succeed in acquiring heaven and merit? After
> having observed a fast, what should one give away, O king? O, tell me,
> what those duties are by which one may succeed in obtaining such
> objects as lead to happiness?'

Do any other statements from any *scripture* comment on this? I mean, do any other statement from any scripture also mention that foreigners were aware of fasting, which is one of the integral ritual of Sanathan dharma, in previous yugas.

*Note*: I want answer only from scriptures, as I told, not from the opinions or books by historians, archeologists, modern experts, etc.,  (which this site is not intended for).

Comment: From now on we should all add a note at the end like you did .. that's one way of preventing the non sense that's going on ..